# Unable to trigger jquery function on checkbox check

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have built a form and am trying to trigger a function when the singular checkbox is clicked, but the function I am using as shown below does not work. Basically every response I could find related to this question points to using the same method that I am using from what I can tell, but I must be doing something wrong here.

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="checkbox" id="check-3dAnimationVisualEffects">
          <input type="checkbox" id="filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects" name="3dAnimationVisualEffects" value="1" class="form-checkbox"/>
          <label for="filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><span>3D Animation Visual Effects</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  if ($('#filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects').is(':checked')) {
    alert("Checked!");
  }
});
</script>
```

How can I get this function to run when the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should attach event handler function for click event using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  $('#filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="checkbox" id="check-3dAnimationVisualEffects">
          <input type="checkbox" id="filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects" name="3dAnimationVisualEffects" value="1" class="form-checkbox"/>
          <label for="filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><span>3D Animation Visual Effects</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form and jQuery function work fine but there is a misunderstanding in how your code logic actually work:

```
if ($('#filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects').is(':checked')) {
    alert("Checked!");
}
```

This condition only work when your checkbox is already checked before executing this jQuery function.

If you try to check and then uncheck it, it won't work as you expected

You should add a click event callback function to perform an action when a checkbox is checked or unchecked :

```
$('#filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects').on('click', function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        alert("Checked!");
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can also trigger events when it is unchecked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      alert('checked');
    else
      alert('not checked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="checkbox" id="check-3dAnimationVisualEffects">
          <input type="checkbox" id="filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects" name="3dAnimationVisualEffects" value="1" class="form-checkbox" />
          <label for="filter-3dAnimationVisualEffects" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><span>3D Animation Visual Effects</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```